# How to get the length of array inside the list of array from api response - flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

This is the api response. I have to get the length of "newslikes" length?

How can i get that. Please help.

{
"sno": 69,
"userid": "ram@gmail.com",
"postUrl": "[https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/69_0.jpg@ https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/69_1.jpg@ https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/69_2.jpg]",
"contentType": "img",
"descrip": "jpg or jpeg 3flrs",
"dispname": "Ram",
"city": "4",
"chamberName": "null",
"keydesc": "null",
"profilepic": "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/profile-images/1274.jpg",
"createdBy": "null",
"postStatus": "Y",
"createdDate": "2022-07-03T11:52:49.000+0000",
***"newsLikes"***: [
{
"sno": 472,
"nfid": 69,
"userid": "newdirector@mailinator.com",
"status": "Y",
"disName": "prathap s",
"disUrl": null,
"createdBy": "newdirector@mailinator.com",
"createdDate": "2022-07-04T04:54:01.000+0000",
"updatedDate": "2022-07-04T04:54:01.000+0000"
},
{
"sno": 478,
"nfid": 69,
"userid": "sriram@gmail.com",
"status": "Y",
"disName": "sri            Ram",
"disUrl": "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/profile-images/1284.png",
"createdBy": "sriram@gmail.com",
"createdDate": "2022-07-04T05:02:13.000+0000",
"updatedDate": "2022-07-04T05:02:13.000+0000"
},
{
"sno": 479,
"nfid": 69,
"userid": "sriram@gmail.com",
"status": "Y",
"disName": "sri            Ram",
"disUrl": "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/profile-images/1284.png",
"createdBy": "sriram@gmail.com",
"createdDate": "2022-07-04T05:02:13.000+0000",
"updatedDate": "2022-07-04T05:02:13.000+0000"
},
{
"sno": 480,
"nfid": 69,
"userid": "sriram@gmail.com",
"status": "D",
"disName": "sri            Ram",
"disUrl": "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/profile-images/1284.png",
"createdBy": "sriram@gmail.com",
"createdDate": "2022-07-04T05:02:36.000+0000",
"updatedDate": "2022-07-04T05:21:43.000+0000"
},
{
"sno": 481,
"nfid": 69,
"userid": "sriram@gmail.com",
"status": "Y",
"disName": "sri            Ram",
"disUrl": "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/profile-images/1284.png",
"createdBy": "sriram@gmail.com",
"createdDate": "2022-07-04T05:02:36.000+0000",
"updatedDate": "2022-07-04T05:02:36.000+0000"
},
{
"sno": 499,
"nfid": 69,
"userid": "rajesh@gmail.com",
"status": "Y",
"disName": "rajesh kumar",
"disUrl": null,
"createdBy": "rajesh@gmail.com",
"createdDate": "2022-07-04T05:48:57.000+0000",
"updatedDate": "2022-07-04T05:48:57.000+0000"
},
{
"sno": 500,
"nfid": 69,
"userid": "rajesh@gmail.com",
"status": "Y",
"disName": "rajesh kumar",
"disUrl": null,
"createdBy": "rajesh@gmail.com",
"createdDate": "2022-07-04T05:48:57.000+0000",
"updatedDate": "2022-07-04T05:48:57.000+0000"
},
{
"sno": 501,
"nfid": 69,
"userid": "rajesh@gmail.com",
"status": "Y",
"disName": "rajesh kumar",
"disUrl": null,
"createdBy": "rajesh@gmail.com",
"createdDate": "2022-07-04T05:48:57.000+0000",
"updatedDate": "2022-07-04T05:48:57.000+0000"
}
]
},

Comment: What do you want to get? I don't understand the question. Also, did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: hi @Jungwon, i am having the "newsLikes" as list inside "data" for ex: 
data = [
"newsLikes": [
{
"sno": 474,
}
]
]

I can get the length of "data". But i have to get the length of "newslikes" inside the "data".

How can i get it?

Comment: Have you checked that the data is responed in the current dart code?

Comment: dart code? I cant get your question

Comment: Do you want to find the length of an array called `newsLikes' that exists inside the array?

Comment: yes. i want length of "newsLikes" inside the DATA.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your JSON is wrong try with this json.

```
{
  "sno": 69,
  "userid": "ram@gmail.com",
  "postUrl": [
    "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/69_0.jpg",
    " https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/69_1.jpg",
    " https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/news-feed/69_2.jpg"
  ],
  "contentType": "img",
  "descrip": "jpg or jpeg 3flrs",
  "dispname": "Ram",
  "city": "4",
  "chamberName": "null",
  "keydesc": "null",
  "profilepic": "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/profile-images/1274.jpg",
  "createdBy": "null",
  "postStatus": "Y",
  "createdDate": "2022-07-03T11:52:49.000+0000",
  "newsLikes": [
    {
      "sno": 472,
      "nfid": 69,
      "userid": "newdirector@mailinator.com",
      "status": "Y",
      "disName": "prathap s",
      "disUrl": null,
      "createdBy": "newdirector@mailinator.com",
      "createdDate": "2022-07-04T04:54:01.000+0000",
      "updatedDate": "2022-07-04T04:54:01.000+0000"
    },
    {
      "sno": 478,
      "nfid": 69,
      "userid": "sriram@gmail.com",
      "status": "Y",
      "disName": "sri Ram",
      "disUrl": "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/profile-images/1284.png",
      "createdBy": "sriram@gmail.com",
      "createdDate": "2022-07-04T05:02:13.000+0000",
      "updatedDate": "2022-07-04T05:02:13.000+0000"
    },
    {
      "sno": 481,
      "nfid": 69,
      "userid": "sriram@gmail.com",
      "status": "Y",
      "disName": "sri Ram",
      "disUrl": "https://uat-marc.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/profile-images/1284.png",
      "createdBy": "sriram@gmail.com",
      "createdDate": "2022-07-04T05:02:36.000+0000",
      "updatedDate": "2022-07-04T05:02:36.000+0000"
    },
    {
      "sno": 499,
      "nfid": 69,
      "userid": "rajesh@gmail.com",
      "status": "Y",
      "disName": "rajesh kumar",
      "disUrl": null,
      "createdBy": "rajesh@gmail.com",
      "createdDate": "2022-07-04T05:48:57.000+0000",
      "updatedDate": "2022-07-04T05:48:57.000+0000"
    },
    {
      "sno": 500,
      "nfid": 69,
      "userid": "rajesh@gmail.com",
      "status": "Y",
      "disName": "rajesh kumar",
      "disUrl": null,
      "createdBy": "rajesh@gmail.com",
      "createdDate": "2022-07-04T05:48:57.000+0000",
      "updatedDate": "2022-07-04T05:48:57.000+0000"
    },
    {
      "sno": 501,
      "nfid": 69,
      "userid": "rajesh@gmail.com",
      "status": "Y",
      "disName": "rajesh kumar",
      "disUrl": null,
      "createdBy": "rajesh@gmail.com",
      "createdDate": "2022-07-04T05:48:57.000+0000",
      "updatedDate": "2022-07-04T05:48:57.000+0000"
    }
  ]
}
```

try to create model with this converter
https://ashamp.github.io/jsonToDartModel/

then

```
YourClassName.newsLikes.length
```

you will get length of **newsLikes**.

Comment: i converted to api response as model from https://app.quicktype.io/. So how can i get the length of news likes?

Comment: `YourClassName.newsLikes.length` This is the length of newsLikes.

Comment: @siva still you can use it like this there is no such major change.
If you still can't get it then attach your code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a type defined for the API response and you mapped your API response to the type you can use

```
data[index].newsLikes.length
```

Or if you have not defined type, you can use like

```
data[index]['newsLikes'].length
```

Add null check wherever it is required and hope you would have parsed the JSON from JSON string if in case you receive JSON String as the response.